# How to map with this Entity model (JPA)?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have below table structure. I just need to read data from these tables. I don't have control over table structure.

There is foreign key on other tables to join with Transaction table. But TABLE_A to TABLE_D is having related data that is having common X_ID.

```
+-------------+ 
| Transaction | 
+-------------+
| T_ID        | 
| Colls       |
+-------------+

+-------------+ 
| TABLE_A     | 
+-------------+
| A_ID        |
| T_ID        | FK to Transaction Table
| X_ID        |
+-------------+

+-------------+ 
| TABLE_B     | 
+-------------+
| B_ID        |
| T_ID        | FK to Transaction Table
| X_ID        |
+-------------+

+-------------+ 
| TABLE_C     | 
+-------------+
| C_ID        |
| T_ID        | FK to Transaction Table
| X_ID        |
+-------------+

+-------------+ 
| TABLE_D     | 
+-------------+
| D_ID        |
| T_ID        | FK to Transaction Table
| X_ID        |
+-------------+
```

My current solution is like below

```
@Entity
public class TransactionEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "transaction_id")
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "t_id")
  @MapKey(name = "x_id")
  private Map<Long, TableA> tablea;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "t_id")
  @MapKey(name = "x_id")
  private Map<Long, TableB> tableb;


  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "t_id")
  @MapKey(name = "x_id")
  private Map<Long, TableC> tablec;


  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "t_id")
  @MapKey(name = "x_id")
  private Map<Long, TableD> tabled;

}
```

Then process TABLE_* details in java code to group them together based on X_ID. I need to represent these data in blow json.

```
{
  "t_id": 1,
  "x_data": [
    "x_id": 1234,
    "table_a": {

    },
    "table_b": {

    },
    "table_c": {

    },
    "table_d": {

    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any better way to achieve this JPA?

Comment: Relationship between the Transaction table and other tables are OneToOne or OneToMany? By JSON it looks like OneToOne

Comment: OneToMany as there can be multiple table_* entities. But their data is spread across multiple table_* tables with x_id as identifier. Each table_* has PK as well seperate from x_id.